# Convert XML to JSON and then deserialize to object

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I'm developing an ASP.NET MVC application with .Net Framework 4.7 and JSON.NET 10.0.2.

I want to load a xml document, convert it to JSON and then deserialize to object. I want to do this because I want to use JSON files and also XML files.

This is the class I want to create with the file:

```
public class ProductionOrderFile
{
    public string ProductionOrderName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public List<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
    public List<AggregationLevelConfiguration> Levels { get; set; }
    public List<VariableData> VariableData { get; set; }
}
```

This is the class that deserialize to the object:

```
private ProductionOrderFile ParseProductionOrderFile(Stream inputStream)
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(inputStream);

    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductionOrderFile>(jsonText);
}
```

This is the XML document:

```
<ProductionOrderFile>
    <ProductionOrderName>"ProOrd_Xml_001"</ProductionOrderName>
    <ProductCode>Pro_EU_001</ProductCode>
    <Batches>
        <Name>Lote_Xml_01</Name>
    </Batches>
    <Levels>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <Name>Nivel_1</Name>
        <PkgRatio>120</PkgRatio>
    </Levels>
    <Levels>
        <Id>2</Id>
        <Name>Nivel_2</Name>
        <PkgRatio>1</PkgRatio>
    </Levels>
    <VariableData>
        <VariableDataId>01</VariableDataId>
        <LevelId>1</LevelId>
        <Value>Pro_EU_001</Value>
    </VariableData>
    <VariableData>
        <VariableDataId>20</VariableDataId>
        <LevelId>1</LevelId>
        <Value>Lote_Xml_01</Value>
    </VariableData>
    <VariableData>
        <VariableDataId>11</VariableDataId>
        <LevelId>1</LevelId>
        <Value>170101</Value>
    </VariableData>
    <VariableData>
        <VariableDataId>17</VariableDataId>
        <LevelId>1</LevelId>
        <Value>210101</Value>
    </VariableData>
    <VariableData>
        <VariableDataId>21</VariableDataId>
        <LevelId>1</LevelId>
        <Value>####################</Value>
    </VariableData>
</ProductionOrderFile>
```

And this is the `jsonText` var content:

```
{
    "ProductionOrderFile": {
        "ProductionOrderName": "\"ProOrd_Xml_001\"",
        "ProductCode": "Pro_EU_001",
        "Batches": {
            "Name": "Lote_Xml_01"
        },
        "Levels": [{
            "Id": "1",
            "Name": "Nivel_1",
            "PkgRatio": "120"
        }, {
            "Id": "2",
            "Name": "Nivel_2",
            "PkgRatio": "1"
        }],
        "VariableData": [{
            "VariableDataId": "01",
            "LevelId": "1",
            "Value": "Pro_EU_001"
        }, {
            "VariableDataId": "20",
            "LevelId": "1",
            "Value": "Lote_Xml_01"
        }, {
            "VariableDataId": "11",
            "LevelId": "1",
            "Value": "170101"
        }, {
            "VariableDataId": "17",
            "LevelId": "1",
            "Value": "210101"
        }, {
            "VariableDataId": "21",
            "LevelId": "1",
            "Value": "####################"
        }]
    }
}
```

But this `return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductionOrderFile>(jsonText);` returns an instance of `ProductionOrderFile` with all of its properties null.

Maybe the problem is that the XML document doesn't have the right format.

Has the XML document the right format?
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you convert it to JSON if your aim is really to create an object? Just use LINQ to XML or similar to convert the XML directly.

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to do this because I want to use JSON files and also XML files. The question is: **Has the XML the right format?**

Comment: I still don't see why you're forced to convert from XML to JSON just because elsewhere you want to use JSON. It strikes me that if you didn't do that, you'd be fine - because presumably elsewhere you use JSON which doesn't have the extra root element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to deserialize your XML is to do so in one step using [`XmlSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).  You can do this by marking your `List<T>` properties with [`[XmlElement]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.aspx) to indicate they should be serialized as a collection of repeated elements without an outer container element:

```
public class ProductionOrderFile
{
    public string ProductionOrderName { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public List<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public List<AggregationLevelConfiguration> Levels { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement]
    public List<VariableData> VariableData { get; set; }
}
```

And then do:

```
private ProductionOrderFile ParseProductionOrderFile(Stream inputStream)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ProductionOrderFile));
    return (ProductionOrderFile)serializer.Deserialize(inputStream);
}
```

Sample [fiddle #1](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FQE8WI).

That being said, if you insist on a two-step deserialization process using an intermediate `XmlDocument`, you need to modify your code as follows:

1. Omit the root element by using [`JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true)`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeXmlNode_2.htm) when creating your intermediate `jsonText`.

   This removes the root `"ProductionOrderFile": { ... }` property that does not appear in `ProductionOrderFile` and bubbles the nested properties up to the top level.
2. Force the `<Batches>`, `<Levels>` and `<VariableData>` element(s) to be converted to JSON as arrays by following the instructions from [Convert XML to JSON and force array](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ConvertXmlToJsonForceArray.htm).

Thus your code becomes:

```
private ProductionOrderFile ParseProductionOrderFile(Stream inputStream)
{
    // var serializer = new JsonSerializer(); Not needed
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(inputStream);

    foreach (var xPath in new [] { "//Batches", "//Levels", "//VariableData" })
    {
        foreach (var node in doc.SelectNodes(xPath).Cast<XmlElement>())
        {
            node.SetAttribute("xmlns:json", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json");
            node.SetAttribute("Array", "http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json", XmlConvert.ToString(true));
        }
    }

    string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(doc, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, true);

    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ProductionOrderFile>(jsonText);
}
```

Sample [fiddle #2](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6J2sru).